# Handling scope in Spring Controllers?

Tags: java, spring

New to Spring and scope handling, as well as 'best practices' involving Spring.

During the development of my application, it came to my attention that issues may arise when the same controller gets accessed. Consider the following scenario:

- User 1 accesses the homepage via its respective controller. This bean (the controller) initializes. Private variables of this controller are initialized: **`@Autowired private String myString = null;`**
- User 1 enters data into a form, and updates the value of **`myString`** to **`myString = "hello world!`**, and uses this new value elsewhere on the page.
- User 2 accesses the page while User 1 is still using the homepage bean. A new request for the Homepage controller bean is issued by User 2.
- User 2 fills out form data, and changes the value of **`myString`** to **`Not Hello World!`**. User 1 believes the value is still `Hello world!`, but it is not... *it has a been changed*!
- User 1 and User 2 both believe they are making changes specific to them, when in reality, they are overwriting one another's changes.

Assuming the above is true, consider my following `@Controller`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class HomepageController {

    private BillableUnit billableUnit;                //bean
    private Template template;                        //bean
    private GriefEditorController griefController;    //bean

    @GetMapping("/homepage")
    public String getHomepage(Model theModel) {

        theModel.addAttribute("userName", "");

        return griefController.loadGrief(theModel);
    }

    @GetMapping("/manager")
    public String getAddPlatform(Model theModel) {

        theModel.addAttribute("billableUnit", billableUnit);
        theModel.addAttribute("template", template);

        return "ManagerView";
    }


    @GetMapping("/save/bill")
    public void saveBillableUnit(Model theModel) {

        try {
        BillableUnit billableUnit = (BillableUnit) theModel.getAttribute("billableUnit");

        Session session = Statics.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(billableUnit);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

        session.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @GetMapping("/save/temp")
    public void saveTemplate(Model theModel) {

        try {
            Template template = (Template) theModel.getAttribute("template");

            Session session = Statics.getSessionFactory().openSession();

            session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(template);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            session.close();

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public GriefEditorController getGriefController() {
        return griefController;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setGriefController(GriefEditorController griefController) {
        this.griefController = griefController;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setBillableUnit(BillableUnit billableUnit) {
        this.billableUnit = billableUnit;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setTemplate(Template template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

}
```

I believe my `@Controller` holds state due to the presence of instance variables. I know I should probably move these out of the class, but to be honest I'm not sure how without breaking the functionality I have created.

> How does one handle state with @Controller?

Comment: Spring beans by default are singletons. So, keeping there a common variable is a bad idea. Instead try to use a request or a session scope, for example, if you need to keep the data in that instance. Here is a little guide: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-bean-scopes

Comment: I can fix this by simply adding an @Scope("prototype") to the class, but this is considered bad practice. I do not want to do this; I want to keep the controller stateless.

Comment: Also instead of creating transactions manually, you can use the @Transactional annotation. In this case Spring will create a transaction itself.

Comment: you can pass on all the parameters you want in bean methods and not have them as properties

Comment: @KalpeshSoni I tried this, however one of the beans internally is not instantiated for some reason. The "RecordId" object within the BillableUnit object is not instantiated, despite being tagged with `@Autowired`

Comment: Why don't you use ThreadLocal?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas Not familiar with ThreadLocal

Comment: What Ilya said. You want stateful sessions, use session scope.